# Javascript setTimeout and jQuery ajaxget loop?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using a China CMS 'Discuz!'.
I am doing a plugin for this CMS. Now I was get stuck at the `ajaxget` and `setTimeout`.

The scenario is, user click `<button>Start working</button>`, then I will run a `ajaxget` to execute a the request, after execute, return the result to user webpage, and will `setTimeout` every 10 second. Now my problem is, I don't know how to stop the `setTimeout` when user click `<button onclick="stopworking">stop</button>`.

I can feel my coding bellow is a strange way, but I wish can make it like normal way.

My html side:

```
//ajaxget(url,id);
<div id = "jinengwordarea">
  <button onclick="startworking(1,this);">start working</button>
  <script>
  function startworking(djid,t){
    t.disabled = true;
    ajaxget('plugin.php?id=jineng&do=jineng&djid='+djid+'&ac=ac&formhash=1244&pass=5677&timestamp=1234566','jinengwordarea');
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

After user click the button, my server side will verify all the variable. If successful, will return the below coding to the `div id = jinengwordarea`;

```
<?php
//....much code
if($_GET['do'] == 'jineng'){
  $djid = intval($_GET['djid']);
  //much verify here, after all verify is pass, will return $returntodiv to the html
  $returntodiv = "<div>ITEM NAME </div><div><div class="jinengword">you getting an ore</div><button onclick="stopworking();">Stop</button></div><script>setTimeout(function(){ ajaxget(\'plugin.php?id=jineng&do=jineng&ac=ac&timestamp=THISTIMESTAMP&formhash=HASH&djid='.$djid.'\',\'jinengwordarea\');    }, 10000);</script>";
  echo $returntodiv;
  exit;
}
?>
```

After that, my html side will become:

```
<div id = "jinengwordarea">
  <div>ITEM NAME </div>
  <div>
    <div class="jinengword">you getting an ore</div><button onclick="stopworking();">Stop</button>
  </div>
  <script>setTimeout(function(){ ajaxget(\'plugin.php?id=jineng&do=jineng&ac=ac&timestamp=THISTIMESTAMP&formhash=HASH&djid=1\',\'jinengwordarea\');}, 10000);</script>
 </div>
```

So it can loop every 10 second, but now I don't know how to stop/clear the `setTimeout`? Since I don't have a id for `setTimeout`, I using `clearTimeout();`

If using `clearTimeout();`, how to add/modify my current script? or have other way instead to request & refresh the `div id jinengwordarea` from return of `$returntodiv`?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer the following web page for setTimeout detail:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp